# Movable Type: Specify one category to display in entry

Tags: movabletype

I want to specify one `<CategoryLabel>` in `<MTEntryCategories>` in archive template.

For example my categories are like this (x is selected category in entry):

**Fruit**
--Apple
--Grape

**Drinks**
--Coffee
-x-Beer
--Juice

**Vacation**
--France
-x-UK

In this case I want to display the label under "Drinks" in a entry (sample code)

```
<MTSubCategories category="Drinks">
   <MTEntryCategories>
       <h1><$MTcategory_label$><h1>
   </MTEntryCategories>
</MTSubCategories>
```

I know there are various plugin that do this but I couldn't find one that supports MT5.
If anyone know if there is a way to do this without the plugins, greatly appreciated!

Comment: So you want to display "Beer" as an h1?  But not "UK"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you would like to do display the category for the entry that is a sub-category of Drinks in an h1.

If that is the case, here is what I would do in MT4 (without a plugin):

```
<mt:entrycategories>
    <mt:ifisdescendant parent="Drinks">
        <h1><mt:categorylabel></h1>
    </mt:ifisdescendant>
</mt:entrycategories>
```

This will step through each of the categories for the entry and, if the category is a sub-category of Drinks, it will output the label in an h1.